# PhpStorm не открывает файлы с расширениями hbs и ejs

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, ejs, hbs

PhpStorm не понимает и не открывает файлы ejs или hbs.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Плагины скачал,перезагрузил, не помогает.
Что еще можно попробовать?Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким поведением?

пс файл 
[idea.log](http://www.mydailycode.ru/catalogs/reserv/idea.log)

[filetypes.xml](http://www.mydailycode.ru/catalogs/reserv/filetypes.xml)

Comment: а каким образом вы их скачали и установили? Предоставьте Ваш idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-usa/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files), пожалуйста

Comment: Settings -> Plugins -> Marketplace, добавил файл

Comment: судя по логу, с плагинами все в порядке. Возможно, проблема с ассоциациями файлов. Пришлите, пожалуйста, файл `C:\Users\Tigran\.PhpStorm2018.3\config\options\filetypes.xml` (если такой есть, конечно)

Comment: добавил файл filetypes.xml

Answer (score 1):

Оба расширения ассоциированы с типом файла **Files Opened in Associated Applications**, т.е. PhpStorm пытается использовать файловые ассоциации, установленные в системе, чтобы открыть файл в соответствующем приложении:

```
<mapping ext="hbs" type="Native"/>
<mapping ext="ejs" type="Native"/>
```

Попробуйте убрать `*.hbs`и `*.ejs` из списка паттернов, ассоциированных с этим типом, в **Settings | Editor | File Types | Files Opened in Associated Applications** и добавить эти расширения к нужным типам файлов (**Handlebars/Mustache** и **EJS Combines...**) соответственно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за старания но не помогло

Comment: и как теперь выглядит ваш `filetypes.xml`?

Comment: буду у компа скину файл